# Magento checkout_cart_product_add_before and get number of products added

Tags: magento, observers

I created the event checkout_cart_product_add_before:
http://markshust.com/2012/08/27/create-checkout_cart_product_add_before-observer-magento

Hoever when I do this the getQuoteItem() seems to be unavailable, so I cannot get to the number of products added to cart. When I use the _after method I can use:

```
public function checkStock2($observer) {
  Mage::log("Check stock before");
  $request = $observer->getQuoteItem();
  Mage::log("q in order = " .$request['qty'] ."");
}
```

However when I am before I cannot reach the getQuoteItem as it is not there yet. Is there a way I could get the number of products the user is trying to add to the cart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you implemented the linked observer, you're missing the information you need.
You have to add the request in your dispatchEvent, in order to check what the user chose :

```
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
    {
        $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
        $request = $this->_getProductRequest($requestInfo);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_before', array(
             'product' => $product,
              'request' => $request
        ));

        return parent::addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo);
    }
```

Then you'll be able to retrieve the user quantity in your observer with :

```
$observer->getEvent()->getRequest()->getQty();
```

the `->getRequest()` method refers to a magic getter for the "request" parameter of your dispatchEvent.

Comment: Hi Bixi, thanks for that. That was indeed the problem. Hint for anyone else looking at this, please notice that the line in the code above that starts with Mage::dispatchEvent is longer than Stackoverflow shows. Scroll to the right to see everything.

Comment: This article might also be helpful: http://www.crearegroup-ecommerce.co.uk/blog/magento-tips/using-a-controller-observer-to-dispatch-your-own-event.php